# Send data to function in Oracle from Java Class

Tags: java, oracle, playframework

I need to send five paramenters to a function in Oracle Database. I am using Playframework and I am reading the data from views without any problems. But now the chalenge is how to send data by java class. Somebody can help me? Is it right this way?

```
package models;

import java.sql.*;
import oracle.sql.ARRAY;
import oracle.jdbc.OracleCallableStatement;
import oracle.sql.ArrayDescriptor;

public class TestDatabase {
    public static void main(String args[]){
        try{
            Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver");

            Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@address","user","pass");

            // Convert your lists to arrays using #toArray( T[] )

            String[] appoEvents    = new String[4];
            appoEvents[0] = "test";
            appoEvents[1] = "internal";
            appoEvents[2] = "123456";
            appoEvents[3] = "2017-10-25 17:00:00";
            appoEvents[4] = "2017-10-25 19:00:00";

            CallableStatement st = con.prepareCall("{ call CORV5_WEB_STORE_APPOINTMENT( :appoEvents )}");

            // Passing an array to the procedure -

            ((OracleCallableStatement) st).setARRAYAtName("test",appoEvents);
            st.execute();
        } catch(ClassNotFoundException | SQLException e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: this might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15246245/create-and-use-a-stored-procedure-with-play-framework-and-jpa

Comment: Thank you very much!!!! It's working and I'm very happy because it was my first time with this connection from Play and Oracle. I was working with views and no problems with Ebean to read all the data. But the process to send back it was a path that I didn't used yet. Have a nice week @CyrilleMODIANO